# Complex nested Dict to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

My dictionary

```
{'count': 1608,
 'results': [{'entity': {'alternativeTitles': [],
    'originalPublishers': [{'administratorPublishers': [{'id': None,
        'ipId': '7040761',
        'publisherName': 'THE ROYALTY NETWORK INC.',
        'ipiNumber': '00255217086',
        'hfaPublisherNumber': 'P1343F',
        'publisherShare': 45,
        'amend': False,
        'email': None,
        'phone': '+1-212-967-4300',
        'website': None,
        'mailingAddress': 'THE ROYALTY NETWORK,  INC., THE ROYALTY NETWORK INC., 224 WEST 30TH STREET, STE. 1007, NEW YORK, NY, USA, 10001',
        'hfaAgreement': False}],
      'writers': [],
      'isTopPublisher': False,
      'id': None,
      'ipId': '7305902',
      'publisherName': 'WESTBURY MUSIC LTD',
      'ipiNumber': '00144443097',
      'publisherShare': 0,
      'amend': False,
      'totalWorks': None,
      'hfaPublisherNumber': 'P9669N',
      'associatedUsers': 0,
      'email': None,
      'phone': '',
      'website': None,
      'mailingAddress': '',
      'hfaAgreement': False},
     {'administratorPublishers': [{'id': None,
        'ipId': '7304677',
        'publisherName': 'ROYNET MUSIC',
        'ipiNumber': '00339668123',
        'hfaPublisherNumber': 'P9713E',
        'publisherShare': 50,
        'amend': False,
        'email': None,
        'phone': '+1-212-967-4300',
        'website': None,
        'mailingAddress': 'THE ROYALTY NETWORK,  INC., ROYNET MUSIC, 224 WEST 30TH STREET, STE. 1007, NEW YORK, NY, USA, 10001',
        'hfaAgreement': False}],
      'writers': [],
      'isTopPublisher': False,
      'id': None,
      'ipId': '7305902',
      'publisherName': 'WESTBURY MUSIC LTD',
      'ipiNumber': '00144443097',
      'publisherShare': 0,
      'amend': False,
      'totalWorks': None,
      'hfaPublisherNumber': 'P9669N',
      'associatedUsers': 0,
      'email': None,
      'phone': '',
      'website': None,
      'mailingAddress': '',
      'hfaAgreement': False}],
    'writers': [{'id': None,
      'localId': None,
      'ipId': '11395522',
      'firstName': 'TIM',
      'lastName': 'ATACK',
      'ipiNumber': '00121504722',
      'roleCode': 10,
      'writerShare': 0,
      'amend': False,
      'worksCount': 0},
     {'id': None,
      'localId': None,
      'ipId': '8516232',
      'firstName': "DES'REE",
      'lastName': 'WEEKES',
      'ipiNumber': '',
      'roleCode': 10,
      'writerShare': 0,
      'amend': False,
      'worksCount': 0}],
    'recordings': [{'id': None,
      'title': 'KISSING YOU LOVE',
      'artistName': '',
      'isrc': 'GBMJG1200449',
      'duration': '00:00',
      'publishOwner': None,
      'publishYear': None,
      'albumTitle': None,
      'label': 'THE CAIRN STRIN',
      'releaseDate': '2017-06-30 00:00:00',
      'amend': False},
     {'id': None,
      'title': 'KISSING YOU LOVE',
      'artistName': "DES'REE",
      'isrc': None,
      'duration': '00:00',
      'publishOwner': None,
      'publishYear': None,
      'albumTitle': None,
      'label': '',
      'releaseDate': '',
      'amend': False}],
    'oldDerivative': None,
    'preTerminationEndDate': None,
    'terminationDate': None,
    'holdTypeId': 0,
    'id': 810545286,
    'title': 'KISSING YOU LOVE',
    'duration': '00:00',
    'languageCode': None,
    'copyrightOfficeNumber': None,
    'copyrightOfficeDate': None,
    'firstUseRefusalIndicator': False,
    'isComplete': True,
    'propertyId': '810545286',
    'rightsholderProprietaryId': None,
    'iswc': None,
    'updateDate': None,
    'totalKnownShares': 95,
    'registrationHistoryStatus': None,
    'registrationHistoryIndicator': None,
    'registrationHistoryDate': None,
    'submissionDate': None,
    'submissionId': None,
    'songCode': 'KV7LMB'}}],
 'error': None}
```

I want to explode this correctly.

Expected output

| count | results | entity | alternativeTitles | originalPublishers | administratorPublishers | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1608 | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A | N/A |

Continuing the table for better understand

| ipId | publisherName | ipiNumber | hfaPublisherNumber | PublisherShare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7040761 | THE ROYALTY NETWORK INC. | 00255217086 | P1343F | 45 |

My current code

```
result = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()
df = json_normalize(result)
```

This is not exploding the data properly as expected, I want each key(Including nested keys) as a column name.

Comment: How will you handle the nest list in json?

Comment: I have no I idea, I tried to use explode function but its also not helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a multi index dataframe. You can create one from a nested dictionary by iterating over the outer and inner keys is the dictionary.

[This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-dictionary-to-multiindex-dataframe/) shows an example of how this is done:

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd
  
# Nested dictionary to convert it into multiindex dataframe
nested_dict = {'India': {'State': ['Maharashtra', 'West Bengal',
                                   'Uttar Pradesh', 'Bihar', 'Karnataka'],
                         'Capital': ['Mumbai', 'Kolkata', 'Lucknow',
                                     'Patna', 'Bengaluru']},
  
               'America': {'State': ['California', 'Florida', 'Georgia',
                                     'Massachusetts', 'New York'],
                           'Capital': ['Sacramento', 'Tallahassee', 'Atlanta',
                                       'Boston', 'Albany']}}
  
reformed_dict = {}
for outerKey, innerDict in nested_dict.items():
    for innerKey, values in innerDict.items():
        reformed_dict[(outerKey, innerKey)] = values
  
# Display multiindex dataframe
multiIndex_df = pd.DataFrame(reformed_dict)
multiIndex_df
```